# Spring boot cross-reference issue randomly occurs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, cross-reference

I got a circular dependencies (cross-reference) issue when building a Spring boot project, and the dependencies trend like below:

- **Processor** class autowired Criteria class via the constructor injection;
- **Criteria** class autowired CacheManager via the constructor injection;
- **CahceManager** class autowired the RuleSet class via the setter injection;
- **RuleSet** class autowired the Processor again via the constructor injection.

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
   app
┌─────┐
|  XXXProcessor defined in file ...
↑     ↓
|  XXXCriteria defined in file ...
↑     ↓
|  XXXCacheManager
↑     ↓
|  XXXRuleSet defined in file ...
└─────┘
```

While I can make an effort to remove the dependency of **Processor** from **RuleSet** class, I was wondering if there is a way of keeping the current references but still eliminating the cross-reference issue as presented here? I looked up this forum and someone suggested that the **@Lazy** annotation might help. I tried to apply it to either the Processor class or the RuleSet class (on either class level or method level), the issue didn't go away.

Another observation is that, the above quoted error didn't appear all the time - sometime the program proceeds just fine, it's that the error randomly occurs that bugged me. And why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it is to replace one instance with a [`Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) like this:

```
public Processor(Provider<Criteria> criteria) {
    this.criteria = criteria;
}
```

Then when using it you need to `get()` it first.

```
Criteria c = this.criteria.get();
```

This means that `Processor` can be constructed before `Criteria` since the injected  `Provider` will get the `Criteria` bean once it's ready.

This means that you cannot call `get()` in the constructor or you'll get a runtime error since that would still mean a circular construction dependency.

`@Lazy` just means that Spring should wait with initialising a bean until it is actually requested instead of eagerly creating it on startup (which is standard behaviour). This has zero impact on both circular dependencies and beans that are injected into other beans constructors. It is useful for beans that are very slow to initialize and must almost always be used from a `Provider` to actually defer initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace constructor injection with field injection in one place. It shall break the cycle of circular objects instantiation.

It's hard to say why does this issue happen from time to time. Perhaps, there are some `@Configuration` classes that build different implementations of the same interface depending on config values. You should provide more details to deal with this problem.